# Getting Error while parsing data using retrofit

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, retrofit2

I have A fragment I need to display review API in this, here is my interface class

```
public interface ApiInterface {
@GET("/businesses")
Call<ArrayList<BusinessesResponse>> getMovie();
```

}

and json response is  :

```
{
"code": 200,
"long_message": "The request was successful and the response body contains the representation requested.",
"short_message": "Record found successfully",
"data": {
    "status": true,
    "count": 8,
    "businesses": [
        {
            "id": 30,
            "title": "best auto body",
            "phone": "4104287884",
            "mobile": null,
            "address": "3600 Dolfield Avenue, Baltimore, MD, USA",
            "lat": "39.3364806",
            "lng": "-76.6752669",
            "category": "Painting",
            "review_ratings": null,
            "total_reviews": "0",
            "avg_rating": null,
            "already_fav": "0",
            "image": "http://karobarlist.xtechnos.com/storage/app/public/business/9ICJ2FFTCwmYVWMsL4qAMXf9ZltREs5Ku1JsIrNK.jpeg"
        },
        {
            "id": 11,
            "title": "Corrib Moving & Storage",
            "phone": null,
            "mobile": null,
            "address": "Dallas, TX, USA",
            "lat": "32.7766642",
            "lng": "-96.79698789999998",
            "category": "Handyman",
            "review_ratings": null,
            "total_reviews": "0",
            "avg_rating": null,
            "already_fav": "1",
            "image": "http://karobarlist.xtechnos.com/storage/app/public/business/s8SQG1Mm1gNLd4uOdU59OzFxDy51N7l7RaJtzbgu.png"
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "title": "NorthStar Moving Company",
            "phone": null,
            "mobile": null,
            "address": "Des Moines International Airport (DSM), Fleur Drive, Des Moines, IA, USA",
            "lat": "41.53413330000001",
            "lng": "-93.65879580000001",
            "category": "Handyman",
            "review_ratings": null,
            "total_reviews": "0",
            "avg_rating": null,
            "already_fav": "1",
            "image": "http://karobarlist.xtechnos.com/storage/app/public/business/fVeQMzZvikHzzvkKwjkghsRKD7wPGC5D7xnIov9M.jpeg"
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "title": "Marcio",
            "phone": null,
            "mobile": null,
            "address": "United States Botanic Garden, Maryland Avenue Southwest, Washington, DC, USA",
            "lat": "38.8881451",
            "lng": "-77.0128833",
            "category": "Painting",
            "review_ratings": null,
            "total_reviews": "0",
            "avg_rating": null,
            "already_fav": "1",
            "image": "http://karobarlist.xtechnos.com/storage/app/public/business/STnuOafrVQUM1z4hBDDUGTc7bnBNiEoZ6DVvQSaM.jpeg"
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "title": "Fast Response Plumbing & Rooter",
            "phone": null,
            "mobile": null,
            "address": "Des Moines International Airport (DSM), Fleur Drive, Des Moines, IA, USA",
            "lat": "41.53413330000001",
            "lng": "-93.65879580000001",
            "category": "Plumbing",
            "review_ratings": null,
            "total_reviews": "0",
            "avg_rating": null,
            "already_fav": "0",
            "image": "http://karobarlist.xtechnos.com/storage/app/public/business/qFsye8cOx8kSeJH9kwHAZG2muf2q74BrTHYV9X80.jpeg"
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "title": "Apollo Heating & Ventilating",
            "phone": null,
            "mobile": null,
            "address": "Square One Shopping Centre, City Centre Drive, Mississauga, ON, Canada",
            "lat": "43.5926695",
            "lng": "-79.6427339",
            "category": "Electricity",
            "review_ratings": null,
            "total_reviews": "0",
            "avg_rating": null,
            "already_fav": "1",
            "image": "http://karobarlist.xtechnos.com/storage/app/public/business/0NfvQ9689mjksRqw7ThjMGx7y73zyvScwTvEAsCX.jpeg"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "title": "Ike’s Electric",
            "phone": null,
            "mobile": null,
            "address": "E.W.R. (EWR), Brewster Road, Newark, NJ, USA",
            "lat": "40.68953140000001",
            "lng": "-74.17446239999998",
            "category": "Electricity",
            "review_ratings": "1_5.0000",
            "total_reviews": "1",
            "avg_rating": "5.0000",
            "already_fav": "1",
            "image": "http://karobarlist.xtechnos.com/storage/app/public/business/CH6XSVuiOD9rT7pS5XUAO4IPOST89jYtPcfiA9vT.jpeg"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "title": "Associated Heating",
            "phone": null,
            "mobile": null,
            "address": "United States Capitol, Washington, DC, USA",
            "lat": "38.8899389",
            "lng": "-77.0090505",
            "category": "A/C",
            "review_ratings": null,
            "total_reviews": "0",
            "avg_rating": null,
            "already_fav": "1",
            "image": "http://karobarlist.xtechnos.com/storage/app/public/business/2mKtZEP82sNwfZx8UWuRnaDnAbDozWW75npRQ22k.jpeg"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

and i am getting Error in fragment :

```
 public void getBusinessList() {


    businessesList = new ArrayList<>();
    ApiInterface apiInterface = NetworkClient.getRetrofitClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<ArrayList<BusinessesResponse>> call = apiInterface.getMovie();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<BusinessesResponse>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<BusinessesResponse>> call, Response<ArrayList<BusinessesResponse>> response) {



            if(response.isSuccessful()) {

                Log.d("MainActivity", "posts loaded from API");
            }else {
                int statusCode  = response.code();





            }


            if (response==null){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Somthing Went Wrong...!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (response.body()==null){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something Went Wrong. List is empty!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                businessesList.addAll(response.body());
                Log.i("RESPONSE: ", ""+response.toString());
            }
            productAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<BusinessesResponse>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unable to fetch json: " + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("ERROR: ", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

and here is my model class i generated online :

```
public class BusinessesResponse {

@SerializedName("code")
@Expose
private Integer code;
@SerializedName("long_message")
@Expose
private String longMessage;
@SerializedName("short_message")
@Expose
private String shortMessage;
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private Data data;

public Integer getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setCode(Integer code) {
    this.code = code;
}

public String getLongMessage() {
    return longMessage;
}

public void setLongMessage(String longMessage) {
    this.longMessage = longMessage;
}

public String getShortMessage() {
    return shortMessage;
}

public void setShortMessage(String shortMessage) {
    this.shortMessage = shortMessage;
}

public Data getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(Data data) {
    this.data = data;
}
```

}

second is :

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
```

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Business {

```
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("title")
@Expose
private String title;
@SerializedName("phone")
@Expose
private Object phone;
@SerializedName("mobile")
@Expose
private Object mobile;
@SerializedName("address")
@Expose
private String address;
@SerializedName("lat")
@Expose
private String lat;
@SerializedName("lng")
@Expose
private String lng;
@SerializedName("category")
@Expose
private String category;
@SerializedName("review_ratings")
@Expose
private Object reviewRatings;
@SerializedName("total_reviews")
@Expose
private String totalReviews;
@SerializedName("avg_rating")
@Expose
private Object avgRating;
@SerializedName("already_fav")
@Expose
private String alreadyFav;
@SerializedName("image")
@Expose
private String image;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public Object getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(Object phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public Object getMobile() {
    return mobile;
}

public void setMobile(Object mobile) {
    this.mobile = mobile;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getLat() {
    return lat;
}

public void setLat(String lat) {
    this.lat = lat;
}

public String getLng() {
    return lng;
}

public void setLng(String lng) {
    this.lng = lng;
}

public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
}

public Object getReviewRatings() {
    return reviewRatings;
}

public void setReviewRatings(Object reviewRatings) {
    this.reviewRatings = reviewRatings;
}

public String getTotalReviews() {
    return totalReviews;
}

public void setTotalReviews(String totalReviews) {
    this.totalReviews = totalReviews;
}

public Object getAvgRating() {
    return avgRating;
}

public void setAvgRating(Object avgRating) {
    this.avgRating = avgRating;
}

public String getAlreadyFav() {
    return alreadyFav;
}

public void setAlreadyFav(String alreadyFav) {
    this.alreadyFav = alreadyFav;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}
```

and the third model class is :

```
public class Data {

@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private Boolean status;
@SerializedName("count")
@Expose
private Integer count;
@SerializedName("businesses")
@Expose
private List<Business> businesses = null;

public Boolean getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(Boolean status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public Integer getCount() {
    return count;
}

public void setCount(Integer count) {
    this.count = count;
}

public List<Business> getBusinesses() {
    return businesses;
}

public void setBusinesses(List<Business> businesses) {
    this.businesses = businesses;
}
```

}

Comment: list is getting empty

Comment: implement Serializable interface on `Data` and `Business` class

Comment: its already as you can see

Comment: API is giving `JSONObject` while you're receiving direct `JSONArray` as BusinessList

Comment: I am using in recyclerview i know I am getting in JSON object

Comment: in Toast getting list is empty

Comment: class Data implements Serializable {....

Comment: i have done i got it still same issue List size 0

Comment: please provide error stack trace